# Angular material pagination next page function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pagination

I follow this tutorial to learn how to make a pagination.

https://github.com/feichao/angular-material-paging

I put a json, myData, with items to see how will work. Because I'm a junior programmer eI got blocked to gotoPage().

In my page I changed:

```
ctrl.total = ctrl.myData.length;
ctrl.currentPage = 1;
ctrl.step = 6;

ctrl.gotoPage = function() {
  if(ctrl.total) {
     for(var i=0; i < ctrl.total; i++) {
            //   
      }
  }
};
```

but I don't know what to put in this function to show me only, let say 10 items, from my json, per page.
You can see these props and methods in their demo.

Can someone please give ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the starting amount and then iterate until you hit the max for that page

```
ctrl.total = ctrl.myData.length; //the total items in your set
ctrl.currentPage = 1; 
ctrl.step = 6; //page size? this could be 10 if you want
ctrl.numpages = ctrl.total/ctrl.step;  //the total number of items partitioned by page size. convert this to a whole number (the ceiling)
 //go to page function here receives the indexes for that page, is that ok?
ctrl.gotoPage = function(Page) { //i modified this to take the page number as an argument
  if(Page<= ctrl.numpages && Page>0) //we need to check that the page is valid
  {
     var startpos = ((Page-1)*(ctrl.step))+1; //this is virtually a skip amount. If its the first page, i = 0, otherwise we start with an increment of the page size. If its the second page, we skip the first 6 results
     for(var i=startpos; i < startpos+ctrl.step; i++) {
            if(i == ctrl.total) //if its the last page we cut it off early
              break;   
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: In my page I use this directive `<wan-material-paging 
      wmp-total="$ctrl.total" 
      goto-page="$ctrl.gotoPage()"
      position="$ctrl.center" 
      current-page="$ctrl.currentPage" 
      step="$ctrl.step">
  </wan-material-paging>`  please tell me where from I will take the Page parameter for $ctrl.gotoPage() ? I mean what should be this parameter?

Comment: i would assume "$ctrl.currentPage". so your next page would be  $ctrl.gotoPage($ctrl.currentPage+1)

Comment: but i am a little confused at what exactly you are trying to do. is the code above what you were looking for?

Comment: My friend, I build a component 1.5 angular version and I used this tutorial with this directive in my component html page. The code is ok, but with  this `current-page="$ctrl.currentPage" `,  in console `Page`, inside js shows me the page that I click but the items are the same in the page.